# How to generate case insensitive string with random module

Tags: python, random

I need to generate random 32-digit number along with 15-character string to get something like `09826843-5112-8345-7619-372151470268` and `qcRtAhieRabnpUaQ`. I use following code to generate number:

```
import random

"-".join(['%08d' % random.randrange(0, 10e7), 
          '%04d' % random.randrange(0, 10e3), 
          '%04d' % random.randrange(0, 10e3), 
          '%04d' % random.randrange(0, 10e3), 
          '%012d' % random.randrange(0, 10e11)])
```

Is there a similar way to create case insensitive 15-char string with just `random` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

rand_cap = [chr(random.randint(65, 90)) for i in range(7)]
rand_small = [chr(random.randint(97, 122)) for i in range(7)]
rand_chars_list = rand_cap + rand_small

random.shuffle(rand_chars_list)

rand_chars = ''.join(rand_chars_list)
```

Comment: This solution is doing random draws without replacement (`shuffle`), where you should be doing with replacement (`sample`).  If you check the question, you'll see that there's two `a`s in the example random string.  Your method can't produce this.

Comment: @wildwilhelm I juts produced ''uEladCFBEatFgA'' (2 `a`s)with above method. What do you mean by "two `a`s in the example random string. Your method can't produce this"?

Comment: This seem to solve the issue, just do edit: you use `rand_cap` and `rand_char_cap` in your code. I suppose these are the same variable.

Comment: Another correction to my comment: `sample` is drawing without replacement as well.  `choice` is the right way to do drawing with replacement, as in @lightalchemist's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
import string
''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 15))

import uuid
str(uuid.uuid4())
```

Comment: Note https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample is without replacement. So, the first approach can't produce a string with two or more similar digits.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import random
import string


def random_string(num_chars, symbols):    
    return "".join(random.choice(symbols)
                   for _ in range(num_chars))


def random_string2(num_chars, symbols, replace=True):
    """Random string with replacement option"""
    symbols = np.asarray(list(symbols))
    return "".join(np.random.choice(symbols, num_chars, replace))

def main():
    print(random_string(15, string.ascii_letters))
    print(random_string2(15, string.ascii_letters, False))
    print(random_string2(15, string.ascii_letters, True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that elements in string need not be unique (which I presume to be the case since "qcRtAhieRabnpUaQ" has 2 'a').

If you want the elements to be unique, then @Sergey Gornostaev's solution is probably the most elegant, but that will impose the number of unique elements in ascii_letters as the longest string you can generate.